# Having trouble parsing Json with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have an android app that sends a json string to my server and it is formatted as follows:

```
{"drink_name":"testing","phone_number":"5555555555"}
```

When I use the command: SELECT * FROM orders, it shows that blank entries were inserted into the table.

I think my issue is arising from my PHP script (mainly because I am new to PHP).
Am I parsing the json correctly?
Below is the script that I wrote.

```
<?php 
$handle = mysql_connect('localhost',USERNAME,PASSWORD); 
if($handle==false) 
{ 
die('No database connection'); 
} 

$db=mysql_select_db('r2bar2');


$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (phone_number, drink_name) 
VALUES ('".$obj->{'phone_number'}."', '".$obj->{'drink_name'}."')");
mysql_close($handle);
?>
```

EDIT:
Here is my Android code if it is any help.

```
protected void sendJson(final String phnNmbr, final String drink) {
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
            HttpResponse response;
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try{
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://kubie.dyndns-home.com/R2Bar2/sendOrder.php");
                json.put("phone_number", phnNmbr);
                json.put("drink_name", drink);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "orders: " + json.toString());  
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);
                /*Checking response */
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(response!=null){
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                //createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
            }
            Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
        }
    };
    t.start();      
}
```

Comment: Well, what does `var_dump($obj)` give you?

Comment: Also, how does the Android app send the data? Is the request a POST or GET?

Comment: try turning on error reporting/error logging and checking the output again.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not entirely sure how I can use var_dump in my case. Can I expect it to try to send the output back to the Android device?

Comment: The app sends the data using HttpPost.

Comment: @kubiej21: Or if you can't do that, use `var_export($obj, true)` to return the dump into a variable, then write it to a file on the server, which can then be retrieved for inspection.

Comment: After writing var_export to a file, all that was displayed was NULL.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` output? If POST is properly made from Android, you should be able to retrieve posted JSON from `$_POST['orders']`.

Comment: @DavidKuridža - When I used var_dump, I wasn't able to get anything to print out. So... I guess its possible that my HttpPost isn't setup correctly. However, I may have just setup the var_dump wrong. Is the following correct syntax? $dumpStr = var_export($_POST);



$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fh, $dumpStr);

fclose($fh);

Comment: Try using `file_put_contents('testFile.txt', print_r($_POST, true));` instead. If it doesn't work, try [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) as well.

Comment: Using print_r returned: **Array()** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. It seems as though I was passing in a raw data type. In order to parse the string, I used the following:

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (phone_number, drink_name)
VALUES ('".$obj->{'phone_number'}."', '".$obj->{'drink_name'}."')");
```

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I had used the same method except for how you are trying to access json data on the server.

I had used $_POST array to access it and it worked well for me. Try using,

```
$json = $_POST['orders'];
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

This had worked perfectly well for me. All the best :)
(I dont think there is a problem with $handle since something is being inserted into the table)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree with you that $handle is not the issue since in a different script of mine, I was able to parse a json array into a table using $_POST. I don't know why its not working for me now though... :/

Answer (score 0):

**You have make a connection to the DB as follws,you have missed the $handle to make connection**

```
$handle = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$handle) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make r2bar2 the current db
$db=mysql_select_db('r2bar2',$handle);
if (!$db) {
    die ('Can\'t use r2bar2 : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but the var_export is still showing that I'm passing NULL to the database.

Comment: check this above code for your database connection.......if success you will get the output as expected..